# Can the "Reborn" race (race template ?) be applied to other creatures?

Tags: dnd-5e, races, ravenloft

Can the "Reborn" race (race template ?) from Van Richten's Guide to Ravenloft be applied to other creatures?

My sister asked if you can use the "Reborn" race (racial template?) to make a Unicorn to humanoid player character, something like Elma from Dragon Maid? Her reason and query is one of the "Origin" options for the Reborn race (racial template) is ["You were magically resurrected but something went wrong."](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/vrgtr/character-creation#Reborn) So, a Unicorn died and soemone tried to resurect her and she turned to a non-centaur humanoid PC she wants to play.

[image: Dragon Maid - Elma]

Answer (score 2):

#### The Reborn Lineage works as a stand-alone race.

The Lineages from *Van Richten’s Guide* are designed to work just fine as a stand-alone races, they do not have to be “applied” to an existing race:

> If you choose a lineage, you might have once been a member of another race, but you aren’t any longer. *You now possess only your lineage’s racial traits.*

So you don’t have to choose one of the existing races to then apply the Reborn lineage to, you can just select the Reborn lineage and fill in your back story however you like - your racial traits are just those described in the Reborn trait list. All the racial traits work without having chosen a different “base” race.

So in your case, *you would retain none of the unicorn’s traits*, you would use *only* the Reborn lineage traits.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. However, what racial traits would carry over  and do they keep their "Legendary Abilities"

Comment: So, again: A lineage from Van Richten's Guide is effectively a "race" unto itself.  There is no carry-over from the species you "really" are.  Mechanically, you're a Reborn and that's it; no unicorn traits whatsoever.  You can *describe* the character as having been changed from another species, even use that as an explanation for their chosen class's supernatural abilities (if any), but nothing from the Unicorn monster transfers over.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver The lineage description tells you which traits carry over (if any).

Comment: For example, if she decides to play a cleric, you might decide that her horn counts as a 'holy symbol' and her magic comes from inside rather than from an external deity.  Mechanically, it's the same as any cleric of whatever domain (I'd probably use Peace from *Tasha's* for the theme but hey get as weird as you wanna), you're just saying "Oh yes, this is a manifestation of your inner unicorn-ness". Or you could go the other way and say her inner magic is all fouled up by the bad rez and she has to learn new ways to fight, if her chosen class doesn't match thematically. Encourage creativity!

Comment: Thats good suggestion. She is gonna play her as  Unicorn/Reborn Celetial Sorcerer, she could use her horn as an arcane focus that sh can't loose unless it gets broken off.

Comment: well, as a merciful GM I'd throw in *aesthetic* traits if you want. Like coloration of the skin or non-functioning appendages (horns unusable for an attack, tails unable to lift items...)